# Jquery datepicker plugin only works for first textbox, not the second

Tags: jquery, html

I have the jquery datepicker plugin, which works fine on the first textbox. You can click it and the calender will popup. Now how do I go about havign it do that on a second textbox? So that when that is clicked, it will also bring the popup up?

Jquery function:

```
    $(function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
});
```

Html input box:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a class like below

```
$(".test").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'}); });
```

Apply to input text by just adding a class.

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="test"/>
<input type="text" id="datepicker2" class="test"/>
```

Comment: do u think it will work? date picker will display when you click the both text boxes but when you use the class the value will retain in first text box so better use two different ids

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use duplicate id's in a page. Give each a different id and then call like this -

```
$('#datepciker1, #datepicker2').datepicker(....
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it isn't working on the second element is because presumably you've given the second input the same ID as the first - [**ID's should be unique**](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqmultiIDs.htm), use a class instead:

```
$(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
});

<input type="text" class="datepicker" />
<input type="text" class="datepicker" />
```